# JPA/Hibernate - ManyToMany with additional columns in join table - "has no persistent id property" for IdClass

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

I am trying to set up a ManyToMany Relationship in JPA with additional columns in the join table.

I followed the example and testcode from here:

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ManyToMany

If I run the code I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: package.ProjectAssociationId has no persistent id property
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindIdClass(AnnotationBinder.java:2507)
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.mapAsIdClass(AnnotationBinder.java:845)
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:671)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processAnnotatedClassesQueue(Configuration.java:3466)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processMetadata(Configuration.java:3420)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1348)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1747)
at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:96)
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:913)
... 51 more
```

I tried to add different annotations to the ProjectAssociationId, but did not get it to work. Do I need any kind of ID in ProjectAssociationId? I don't think so because this is not actually persisted. But about what is hibernate complaining then about exaclty?

This is the code:

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
  @Id
  private long id;
  ...
  @OneToMany(mappedBy="employee")
  private List<ProjectAssociation> projects;
  ...
}
@Entity
public class Project {
  @Id
  private long id;
  ...
  @OneToMany(mappedBy="project")
  private List<ProjectAssociation> employees;
  ...
  // Add an employee to the project.
  // Create an association object for the relationship and set its data.
  public void addEmployee(Employee employee, boolean teamLead) {
    ProjectAssociation association = new ProjectAssociation();
    association.setEmployee(employee);
    association.setProject(this);
    association.setEmployeeId(employee.getId());
    association.setProjectId(this.getId());
    association.setIsTeamLead(teamLead);

    this.employees.add(association);
    // Also add the association object to the employee.
    employee.getProjects().add(association);
  }
}
@Entity
@Table(name="PROJ_EMP")
@IdClass(ProjectAssociationId.class)
public class ProjectAssociation {
  @Id
  private long employeeId;
  @Id
  private long projectId;
  @Column(name="IS_PROJECT_LEAD")
  private boolean isProjectLead;
  @ManyToOne
  @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="EMPLOYEEID", referencedColumnName="ID")
  private Employee employee;
  @ManyToOne
  @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="PROJECTID", referencedColumnName="ID")
  private Project project;
  ...
}
public class ProjectAssociationId implements Serializable {

  private long employeeId;

  private long projectId;
  ...

  public int hashCode() {
    return (int)(employeeId + projectId);
  }

  public boolean equals(Object object) {
    if (object instanceof ProjectAssociationId) {
      ProjectAssociationId otherId = (ProjectAssociationId) object;
      return (otherId.employeeId == this.employeeId) && (otherId.projectId == this.projectId);
    }
    return false;
  }

}
```

Comment: Can you post the code which constructs and saves the entity?

Comment: This post might help you [Many-To-Many Example – Join Table + Extra Column](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-example-join-table-extra-column-annotation/)